# ¿Cómo asignar más recursos en Rstudio?

Tags: r, ejecutar, memoria, hardware

Estoy calculando la función Hermans-Rasson con un conjunto de datos grande(n>15000). Quisiera para que no se demore tanto asignarle más recursos al programa.Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿De que recursos estás hablando? ¿Memoria, disco, cpu?  Ayudaría mucho que plantearas tu pregunta con un ejemplo reproducible.

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo mucho, pero creería que en memoria RAM

Comment: Bueno, en general R trata de reservar la mayor cantidad de memoria que el sistema operativo y hardware le pueda ofrecer. Si no tienes suficiente, no queda otra que actualizar el hardware lamentablemente. Sino se podría estudiar soluciones alternativas, pero eso solo entendiendo que es lo que hace tu código y tu no has dado mucho detalle al respecto.  Trata de armar un ejemplo reproducible y agrégalo a tu pregunta, con eso tal vez se te pueda ayudar de alguna manera.

Comment: Editaré la peregunta para añadir la función y el fragmento del código en la usa.